# docker-machine running on aws debian

Tags: docker, debian, docker-machine

On Debian, installing docker-machine using:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.13.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine &&
  chmod +x /tmp/docker-machine &&
  sudo cp /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

When I try commands like `docker-machine version` or `docker-machine ps` I get nothing at all (not even `command not found`).

`which docker-machine` outputs `/usr/local/bin/docker-machine`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command-line is producing a zero-byte file because you cannot redirect `wget` as you tried to do it.

If you want to store the file under a different name you can use the `-O` flag:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.13.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -O /tmp/docker-machine
```